# Actionscript 2 onRollOver Not Working

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I have named the button (movie clip) as btnStart for the instance.

```
btnStart.onRollOver = function() {
    this.gotoAndStop("Over");
}
```

When the button is hovered, it scales larger, but it doesnt work. The script it in the frame.

Comment: and onpress or onrelease working? may be you should check the name of "Over" frame , may be it's in lowercase. or try to call gotoAndStop(2).

Answer (score 0):

Your code functions with a `btnStart` movieclip I am testing, so the problem is not in your syntax. Perhaps checking the following will help:

`File > Publish Settings...` and ensure that `Script` is set to `Actionscript 2.0`

Try testing the code by placing it directly on the movieclip i.e.

```
on(rollOver){
    this.gotoAndStop("Over");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check the following for extra measure.

You labelled the frame on your (presumably) root timeline "Over" if in doubt perhaps label it to something new. Try "one", cross reference both and check both spelt the same without typos

Try absolute paths.

```
_root.btnStart.onRollOver (assuming your button is on the root timeline and not embedded in another MC)    
_root.gotoAndStop("Over");

btnStart.onRollOver = function() {
this.gotoAndStop("Over");
}
```

Failing all of the above, make an instance on your stage and set it as a Button instead of a Movieclip. This option will be prebuilt into the btn.